# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE procedure in data grip

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip

The procedure `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(max)` doesn't work in data grip and doesn't display anything in the output filed even if the programme is correct , and the `Enable DBMSOUTPU` button activated (`ctrl + F8`) .

Comment: What is "data grip"?  You've tagged this for both Oracle SQL Developer and Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer.  Those are two completely different IDEs.  Are you using one of those IDEs or a different IDE?

Comment: I've updated the tags to remove the irrelevant tags and to add "datagrip". If this is not correct then please [edit] your question to have the correct tags and do not tag unnecessary ones.

Comment: What is the version of DataGrip? Similar bug was fixed in 2021.2. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14367/Enable-DBMSOUTPUT-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14367/Enable-DBMSOUTPUT-not-working) was fixed in DataGrip 2021.2. Just let us know if you experience any further problems.